# How to tell SQLITE to ignore STDIN?

Tags: sqlite

I am executing sqlite as:

`sqlite3 -batch -cmd "select col2 from mytable where col1 = 'myvalue';" mydb`

I want it to execute the select statement and exit, but instead it sits there and waits for further input, wanting an `.exit` command.

I do not have the option of doing `</dev/null` as I am executing the command programmatically and not from a shell script.

How can sqlite3 exit in a one-line command without using shell redirection or pipes?

Comment: Why are you calling the sqlite monitor from another program?  Just use it like it was designed to be; as a library.

Comment: I am doing this because they are the constraints that I have to work with. Do you know how to make it exit after the select statement?

Comment: I guess closing the stdin descriptor of the forked process should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite3 monitor utility treats the first argument that doesn't start with a `-` as the name of the database to open.  Any other arguments after that that aren't switches or switch parameters are treated as commands to be executed as if they were entered from STDIN.  The presence of at least one such command disables parsing from STDIN completely.  That's why `-cmd` exists: it let's you execute commands at the outset and then still enter the STDIN [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).  So you can modify your command line as such:

```
sqlite3 -batch mydb "select col2 from mytable where col1 = 'myvalue'"
```

Just like when compiling a prepared statement through the C API, the semicolon isn't necessary at the end of the query.  Each command line argument is considered a complete statement or `sqlite3` dot-command.